# Is there any helper website that will invert logic/conditional statements in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have if statements in C and occasionally I want to see what the opposite looks like. For example:

```
  if(!foo && bar)
  {
      a = 1;        
  }
  else // foo || !bar
  {
      b = 1;        
  }
```

I want to know when the else part will be used. Now this example is simple so it's `foo || !bar`  right? This is why I want some sort of logic checker or inverter or helper website because I have more complicated examples and I would like to make sure the condition for the else statement is exactly what I think it is.

Thanks

Comment: How about writing your own? Use the following axioms: `!(!a) == a`, `!(a && b) == !a || !b`., `!(a || b) == (!a && !b)`

Comment: It's very easy if you just learn basic boolean algebra.

Comment: [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Answer (score 1):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=not%20(not%20a%20and%20b)) can give you minimal and standard forms of Boolean expressions.